# Appending Numbers

Tags: code-golf, string

A fairly simple challenge: You will receive two inputs, a string and a number (the number may be taken as a string, ie `"123"` instead of `123`)

If the string does not end in a number (ie, it does not match the regex `\d$`), just append the number to the end of the string.

If the string does end in a number (ie, it matches the regex `\d+$`), you should first delete that and then append the number.

Neither of the inputs will ever be invalid or empty (invalid is defined by the numerical input not containing only digits)

The number will never contain a `-` or a `.`.

The string will never contain a newline, or unprintable non-whitespace characters.

### Test Cases:

```
abc123 + 345 -> abc345
123 + 1 -> 1
hello + 33 -> hello33
123abc123 + 0 -> 123abc0
ab3d5 + 55 -> ab3d55
onetwo3 + 3 -> onetwo3
99ninenine + 9999 -> 99ninenine9999
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 5 bytes

```
\d*¶
```

Takes two strings as input, separated by a newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkXr0Dau//8Tk5INjYy5jE1MAQ)

Comment: ninja'd. Though I'm not sure if the space is a good separator choice.

Comment: Fair enough, changed to a tabulator.

Comment: How about a semicolon? That one doesn't need to be escaped either.

Comment: Oh, I just read the OP's clarification. Newline it is.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a.rstrip(`56**7`)+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRCoIwGEbvfYr/7te1Il0rEOxFTHBLxcHahltIT79oFl2e73A@9wqzNVWcmlvU4iEHAYLKWhwWHxbl8p6fCbn0xU7GdVZ6hBLqDHyjjHuGvMjALcoE8BT3V6RTTnwRWxTyXlYMKSA7ceyyFr9YJphHrW2y7Cf/xTFNQrKBf5BvvTVjWO12iR28AQ)

Comment: Nice trick to create a number with all the digits!

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but for me (v2.7.11 on Windows), this fails when `a` ends with `"L"` because `56**7` evaluates to `1727094849536L`. Input of `a="abcdL"; b="59"` outputs `"abcd59"`.  Your TIO link does not evaluate `56**7` to a long so I don't know what is happening

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, <strike>37</strike> <strike>36</strike> <strike>35</strike> 33 bytes

```
<?=chop($argv[1],3**39),$argv[2];
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%c3%b6rg-h%c3%bclsermann).

Comment: `chop` as alias saves 1 Bytes

Answer (score 5):

### Perl 5, 12 bytes

**11 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```
s/\d*$/<>/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZFS0Xfxk4/9f//xKRkQyNjLmMTUy4QbciVkZqTk89lbAziQiUNuBKTjFNMuUxNufLzUkvK84Hq/@UXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA)

Comment: Hehe, came up with exactly the same code! Glab to see you back around :)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 32 bytes

```
a->b->a.replaceAll("\\d*$","")+b
```

Takes input `a` as a String, and for `b` it doesn't matter whether it's a String or integer (although I use Integer in the TIO-link below).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZAxT8MwEIX3/IqTxRBDYlFCpkAkFiQGpo6U4eKY4uDYVnIpqlB/ezBKoFUXInk439P33t01uMPUeWWb@mPUrXcdQRN6YiBtxNtgJWlnxeNcFJE02PfwjNp@RQA9IWkJv/Ldmjptt8mx8WRJbVWXwKSUJch7GDEtq7RE0SlvUKoHY2K22dSXFyxhjF9VYxG8w/NDZYL9nLJzuoY2JMeT2csrIP@ZAmC970m1wg0kfJDI2FgK9N7sY4aVXN1kjM//7DbnvPiXOkVWS4B3ZYw7pmQLQ86mu16CYZXV@R@SL9rHWUWf7uQME3SIDuM3)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
r"%d*$" +V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v0hJNUVLRUlBO@z/f6XEpGQlHQUlE1MzJQA)

```
 r"%d*$" +V
Ur"%d*$" +V # Implicit input (U and V)
 r          # Remove
  "%d*$"    #   any trailing digits
U           #   from the first input
         +V # And append the second input
            # Implicit output
```

Comment: Doesn't work if `U` doesn't end in a number. Try using `*` in the RegEx, instead of `+`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v0hJNUVLRSns/3@lxKRkJR0FJRNTMyUA)

Comment: Now it doesn't work if `U` *does* end in a number. I think you'll have to do `r"%d+$" +V`

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that. Should be fixed now

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>44</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

**EDIT:** -4 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings. I don't use regular expressions much.

**EDIT 2**: -2 bytes thanks to @totallyhuman pointing out that the number could be taken as a string

Had to be expected...

```python
lambda x,y:re.sub("\d*$",y,x)
import re
```

Just removes the digits at the end of the string and appends the number

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9KqKFWvuDRJQykmRUtFSSehMkGnQpMrM7cgv6hEoSj1f0FRZl6JRppGZl5BaYmGpo4CiAvlAMF/pYzUnJx8QyNjJS4TUzMA)

Comment: If you replace your regex with `\d*$`, can you replace the `""` with `` `y`  `` to save some bytes?

Comment: @DomHastings: Nice! I don't use regular expressions much so thanks!

Comment: You can take the `y` parameter as a string too.

Comment: @totallyhuman: Glazed over that detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
a<|XD.b
```

*@DLosc saved me 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0aYmISYlQS/p////5jmJOYmGBv8tLQE)

Explanation

```
a<|         Strip all matches off the end of 'a' (the first cmd line arg)
   XD         of the pattern \d (ordinarily, a regex would be entered as '\d', but digits 
              have a pre-existing constant XD)
     .b     Then concatenate 'b' (the second cmd line arg)
            PIP implicitly prints the results of the last operation.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
import re
re.compile("\d*$").sub
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvNtihVLzk/tyAzJ1VDKSZFS0VJU6@4NOl/QVFmXolGmoZWZl5BaYmGpqbmfyUTUzMlHaWM1JycfEMjYyUA)

Takes the inputs in reverse order, both as string.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
DvTFNÜ}}«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fpSzEze/wnNraQ6v//zc0Mk5MSgaSXAYA)
Probably a bad solution but it's the best I could come up with

#### Explanation

```
DvTFNÜ}}«
Dv     }  # For each character in input1
  TF  }   # 10 times
    NÜ    # Get 0-9 and trim it from input1
        « # Concatenate with input2
```

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a=~/\d*$/;$`+b}
```

Takes two strings in input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k60bZOPyZFS0XfWiVBO6n2f0FpSbFCWrRSYlKyoZGxko6SsYmpUiwXTBgiZogkkpGak5MPUmeMqgxugAGSeGKScYopUMwU2cz8vNSS8nywXUqx/wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
œrØD;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5KLDM1ys/x9erv@oaU3k///R0UqJScmGRsZKOgoKSsYmpkqxOlwK0UpQETBQMoQKZgANyYcIKxkbI1TCTVAygAomJhmnmEJVmsLMzM9LLSnPh5irBNQeCwA)

#### How it works

```
œrØD;  Main link. Left argument: s. Right argument: t

  ØD   Digits; yield "0123456789".
œr     Trim these characters from the right of s.
    ;  Append t.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
x=>y=>x.replace(/\d*$/,y)
```

- 1 byte saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) reminding me why I shouldn't golf early in the morning!

Comment: Is the `?` required?

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 45 bytes

```c#
s=>n=>s.TrimEnd("0123456789".ToCharArray())+n
```

Explanation:

```c#
s=>n=>                                        // Take input
      s.TrimEnd(                              // Trim the end of the string with the specified chars
                "0123456789"                  // Create a string of the digits
                            .ToCharArray())   // Turn the string into a char array
                                           +n // Append the integer onto the end
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>7</s> 4 bytes

```
óä*î
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Dmw0u0Dq/7/7@4pCgzL10hPy9VoSQjsUQhOTFPITk/ryQxM08hMa@yJAMoa2hkzJWYlMxlYmoGAA)

This uses the same regex as the Retina answer above:

```
s:/\d*\n//
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 20 bytes

```
->$_,\n{S/\d*$/{n}/}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl 32 bytes

```
proc s a\ b {regsub \\d*$ $a $b}
```

I'm not sure about the expected interface. This is done as a procedure that accepts the two inputs as call arguments. To turn it to a standalone script that reads input from stdin and outputs the result to stdout, one would need the extra line:

```
puts [s [gets stdin] [gets stdin]]
```

or would do it all "inline":

```
puts [regsub \\d*$ [gets stdin] [gets stdin]]
```

regsub takes an RE, the original string and a string to replace the matching part with.

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), <s>16</s> 21 bytes

```
$^//^.*?(?=\d*$)/S0^#
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/) (input is linefeed separated)

#### Explanation

```
$^                Set the stack-string to be equal to the first line in the input
/                 Set the stack-array to be equal to the matches of this regex:
 /^.*?(?=\d*$)/   The beginning of the string followed by non-digit characters at the end that are not included in the match.
S0                Convert to a string with 0 as the delimiter
^#                Append the rest of the input to the stack-string
```

I had to increase the bytecount by 5 because the code did not work for testcases like `a5b3` with multiple digits.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 48 bytes

There is already a Mathematica solution (84 bytes).

```
StringDrop[StringTrim["."<>#,_?DigitQ..]<>#2,1]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>75 bytes</s> <s>95 bytes</s> <s>91</s> <s>79</s> 61 bytes

```
b=(`notElem`['0'..'9'])
r=reverse
d#e=r(snd$break b$r d)++e
```

I tried doing this without regex so maybe that would be a dramatically improved answer.  Also there are a couple ways I could go about this so I am unsure if I can shave a few bytes with a different approach.

UPDATE: I went up in bytes because I realized I was failing the test case where numbers exist in the string that are not the suffix.  Now I am sure that regex would provide a much better answer.

UPDATE2: After some great feedback, more bytes were golfed!

Comment: ``b=(`elem`['0'..'9'])`` is shorter than `isDigit`+ `import`.  `dropWhile` can be replaced with `snd.span`, i.e. `=r(snd$span b$r d)++e`. If you reverse the test ``b=(`notElem`...)`` you can go with `d#e|b$last$d=d++e|2>1=r(snd$break b$r d)++e`.

Comment: @nimi Thanks for the suggestions!  I keep forgetting about span and break and how useful those can be.

Comment: Can't the `|b$last$d=d++e|2>1` part be simply dropped? All the test cases seem to work fine. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Bi8IwEIXv8yuGWKhSKu1mc@ih3vwVsmDdDFisyZIW97D42@tMWrRuIJD3zcubd276C3XdOIY60I1CT2BXVId172xyCtRc1kfnh31H1@MhLdLtNq3Sr00S0G6yjMa/HJrTd/mhMUP9aTDfIWt@wcRKISWceYcXixYdldZieX4uojGCgiO1NQzNHMjKgHc0/Pq4SOgsoapc60guTyo@MnxBIZDf4dq0Dmu0HgF/QusGTFBN29VKcWG14BMslyh2Fqf@Z3xmFOotmTszNG@5c2eJWeJXW55IYTU@AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni Great idea!  you just golfed me 18 bytes!

Comment: As you can see in the TIO link, `b` can now be in-lined to save some further bytes.

Comment: Finally `(\c->c>'/'&&c>':')` is shorter than `(\`notElem\`['0'..'9'])`, for a total of 51 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RioMwEEXf5yuGKLVFpLppHlzQL@mLNQOVtrFEaR@W/XZ3JkprNyDxnrm5c8/NcKHrdZp85elBfiCwEVV@Ozgbnzw1l@2xzeq2TvbJZsPXd7KLPdpdmtL0k0FzaosvjSnqg8GsRtb8BzMrhBRw5gW9WLTooLQWy@txHowB5ByprWFolkBWBnpH47MPi4QuEsrSdY7k40nJR4ZvKASyX7g1ncMKbY@Ad9@5EWNU83YVKS6sVnyGxRqFzuLU/4yvjFx9JHNnhuYjd@ksMWv8bssTKaymPw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Pointfree `(++).r.snd.break(\c->c>'/'&&c>':').r` is 46 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NDoIwEITv@xSbjRENAcHaAybwJF4QaiRqMcXowfjsuFvxB5s07Xw7nc6@7A7meOx7lztzNa4zsMtnYTiPXdzZOt46Ux5mmyoqqiJYBNMpH@uAp/09gnJbpUuFIaqVxqhA1nyDF0uFpLDn9FYsSrRXSonl8zjxRg8SjlS1ZqiHQFYaWmsut9Z/JHSQkGW2sUY2TzJeMvxCIRA94FQ2FnOsWwQ8u8ZecII7en1PxIXpl3uYjpAvzU71b3xnJDRO5tJEepw7lOaYEf7WJZLC1D8B "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni I feel thoroughly discouraged at this point.  I have so much to learn.

Comment: Don't be! Learning new tricks and things about Haskell I didn't know before are some of my favourite parts of golfing.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 18 bytes

```
sub("[0-9 ]*$",$2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uDRJQynaQNdSIVZLRUlHxUjz/39Ly7zMvFQQVrAEAq7EpGRDI2MFYxNTAA)

This just replaces a string composed of any number of digits and spaces that ends the arguments to the command with the second argument to the command.  It's effectively stripping the commandline and adding back the second argument.  And since there's guaranteed to be a non-empty second argument, the result is truthy and `$0` is printed, which is the modified commandline arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 84 bytes

```
(k=#;T=ToCharacterCode;L=T@k;While[47<Last@L<58,w=k~StringDrop~-1;k=w;L=T@w];w<>#2)&
```

input 2 strings

> ["ab3d5", "55"]

output

> ab3d55

Answer (score 1):

## [Noether](http://github.com/beta-decay/noether), 11 bytes

```
I"\d+$"-I+P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SSJcZCskIi1JK1A&input=ImFiYzEyMyIKIjM0NSI)

When inputting a string, enclose it in quotation marks

***Explanation:***

```
I       - Push input to stack
"\d+$"  - Push string to stack
-       - Remove characters from first string which match the regex
I       - Push input to stack
+       - Append to the first string
P       - Print top item of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

Should be able to golf this down a bit...

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{for(c=strlen(v[1]);~c*isdigit(v[1][--c]);v[1][c]=0);printf(v[1]),puts(v[2]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JcpLDoMgFEbh7QCRpL5GxJUYB/Svj5tYNIBMGt11x7fEzk6@HH5bcgJFklisVyqZz7R5gS5Ev45OpL4cpLmgKLxopnhDrzWy3omhe0ize3Jx@t/FfsSQs8rLycz2ibKquW7ar9s0LJbxBw)

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcnBDoIwDADQ32kLS0TktPAlhMOoAk10km30QuTXq/H0Do/dwmz2ChKBa0VeQyJSf8zvBNznkp6PCFRViv5k50jyXRYpwAPpiP5Pf0G/JYllBlKst71k0KH59cfMwsTNtbX21n0B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 25 bytes

```arturo
$=>[++replace&{/\d+$}""&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Bdi1O1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 77 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func a(s,n string)string{return TrimRight(s,"0123456789")+n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohIFpbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3fSFiekrFJUWZeenFSlxppXnJCokaxTp5ChAxTQhVXZRaUlqUpxBSlJkblJmeUQJUomRgaGRsYmpmbmGppKmdVws11BhsBshKDU2Fai4FIABaqRcANKYkJ08jUUMpMSkZqFNJR0EJqF1JU5MLqnXBAggNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
DþRvyÜ}«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5fC@oLLKw3NqD63@/z8/L7WkPN@YyxgA)

**Explanation:**

```
DþRvyÜ}«
D        Duplicate input.
 þ       Get the digits of the input.
  R      Reverse the digits of the input.
   v  }  For each of the digits in the input:
    y        Push the current digit
     Ü       Trim that from the right of the input.
       « Concatenate to 2nd input.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 28 bytes

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\d+$",)&B1
```